# Track changes in constraint keys in sql server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to create a trigger which logs a table tracking all DDL Changes including:

- CREATE
- ALTER
- DROP

On Tables, views, functions, procedures and index using EventData() and Event Type. This table must log following info of the events

- database name
- schema name
- IP address
- user name
- event type
- modification date etc .

I also want to track add constraint and drop constraint but there is no event type which supports this.

How can I add this to my trigger?

Comment: SSMS: Right-Click -> Reports -> Standard Reports -> Schema Changes History

Comment: @Jenna; Please mark the answer if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 1):

Event type for add/drop constraint is `ALTER_TABLE`

Here is `EventData()` XML for add/drop constraint :

```
<EVENT_INSTANCE>
  <EventType>ALTER_TABLE</EventType>
  <PostTime>2019-12-12T21:44:41.633</PostTime>
  <SPID>54</SPID>
  <ServerName>XAMT-ULTRABOOK</ServerName>
  <LoginName>XAMT-ULTRABOOK\XAMT</LoginName>
  <UserName>dbo</UserName>
  <DatabaseName>AdventureWorks2017</DatabaseName>
  <SchemaName>HumanResources</SchemaName>
  <ObjectName>Department</ObjectName>
  <ObjectType>TABLE</ObjectType>
  <AlterTableActionList>
    <Drop>
      <Constraints>
        <Name>DF_Department_ModifiedDate</Name>
      </Constraints>
    </Drop>
  </AlterTableActionList>
  <TSQLCommand>
    <SetOptions ANSI_NULLS="ON" ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT="ON" ANSI_PADDING="ON" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="ON" ENCRYPTED="FALSE" />
    <CommandText>ALTER TABLE [HumanResources].[Department] DROP CONSTRAINT [DF_Department_ModifiedDate]</CommandText>
  </TSQLCommand>
</EVENT_INSTANCE>
```